# Merging tags [chart] and [charts]

Tags: support, retag-request

[chart](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chart) and [charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charts) should be merged. They refer to the exact same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change chart -> charts has now been completed.